# Moto G Unable to Factory Reset "boot failed"

Tags: factory-reset, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G which spontaneously went to a white screen with a blue "M".  It will only display that screen or a battery level screen.  If an attempt is made to recover or factory reset, it either shows the blue M, or the fastboot program says the boot failed.

What are the tools which are used to recover from this type of a condition, perhaps to load a boot image which will work?

Comment: Which model Moto G, there are dozens... Please edit your original question to include the EXACT model and number, like XT1540 2GB or similar, and whether the bootloader is locked or unlocked.

Comment: XT1045, Device is LOCKED, eMMC 8GB Sandisk RV=06 PV=07 TY=17

Answer (score 1):

This is one of two conditions... either the ROM has been corrupted, or most likely (since recovery won't start) is that the internal emmc chip (internal storage) is defective.

You need to attempt to reflash your device with it's specific factory firmware image. Since you didn't state which model specifically, it is hard to tell you where to go for the answer. (If you update the original question with your specific model and comment on this answer, I can update it to specific links for your device).

To be honest, there is only a 50/50 chance of recovery at this point. The symptoms you describe are most likely a defective internal storage chip.

Comment: Prior symptoms were high heat, low battery life and slow response, for about a week prior to bricking.   An I correct that Andriod SDK will be my friend? I have gotten the Cricket image which it was apparently initially shipped with, or would I use a different factor image?

Comment: @mongo  You must us an image that is the same version or newer of what is on your device. You will need fastboot and access to XDA most likely, this fix isn't officially supported, and to be honest, it likely won't work. Sounds like your device is defective.

Comment: @mongo Actually, the Cricket version might be more difficult as it is more locked down than retail units. I am going to point to you XDA for more assistance since, although I own several Moto devices, I do not own this one. https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/guide-moto-g-4g-lte-xt1045-restore-to-t2826112

Comment: Thanks.  I have given up, until a rainy day, and moved the sim to another phone.  That phone always had a problem after the battery was drained, and sometimes it seemed to drain quickly.  A friend has the same model, for about the same time, and theirs works just fine.